# How to render SCSS while keeping nesting?

Tags: sass, postcss

I am creating a SCSS -> HTML plugin and need to first render SCSS -> CSS while keeping the nesting so I can then parse with PostCSS to then create an HTML tree with.

I would like to render SCSS like this

```
// myMixin.scss
@mixin myMixin {
    .myMixin {
        padding: 1rem;
        background: yellow;
    }
}

// main.scss
@import 'myMixin.scss';
$blue: #004AAD;

.button {
    .text {
        color: $blue;
    }
    @include myMixin;
}
```

And the output would look like this:

```
.button {
    .text {
        color: #004AAD;
    }
    .myMixin {
        padding: 1rem;
        background: yellow;
    }
}
```

Basically, I'd like a way to render everything in SCSS while keeping the original nesting. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: The nesting feature is a part of SCSS. However, CSS that SCSS is compiled to, doesn't have nesting. so the final output will look like `.button .text {` and `.button .myMixin {`, without the nesting.

Comment: in short - browsers understand CSS - not the hybrid whatever you want

Comment: Can you explain why you need this? The “nesting” style is not valid CSS and won’t be interpreted by client browsers as you seem to expect it will.

Comment: @esqew I am creating a SCSS -> HTML plugin and need to first render SCSS -> CSS while keeping the nesting so I can then parse with PostCSS to then create an HTML tree with. My question seems meaningless without context so I guess I should have included context.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting is specific to SCSS. Also I don't think @import is best practice, use @use instead.

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use

Answer (score 0):

Here is the thing our client(browsers) only support raw CSS and not SCSS, When you use SCSS it compiles down to raw CSS, And CSS doesn't have inbuilt Nesting feature.